# How to monkey patch a generic type tag function table

Tags: monkeypatching, dispatch, dynamic-dispatch

I found it interesting to read on one of the ways that you can do functional dynamic dispatch in [sicp](http://www-mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html#%_sec_2.5) - using a table of type tag + name -> functions that you can fetch from or add to.

I was wondering, is this a typical type dispatch mechanism for a dynamic non OO language?

Also what would be the typical way to monkey path this, using a chaining list of tables(if you don't find it in the first table try next table recursively)? Rebind the table within local scope to a modified copy? ect?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but just to clarify, do you mean a type dispatch mechanism used in _implementing_ the language, or as a design pattern _within_ the language? And what, for example, are some other dynamic, non-OO languages besides Scheme/Lisp you'd be interested in hearing about?

Comment: Any of the other languages which have a good deal of thought and development behind them(I'm not thinking of any particular ones),

Comment: I thought that in scheme the difference between language design and useful pattern was small.And I'm interested in either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a typical type dispatch mechanism, even for non-dynamic non-OO languages, based on [this article about the JHC Haskell compiler](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/jhc.shtml) and how it implements type classes. The implication in the article is that most Haskell compilers implement type classes (a kind of type dispatch) by passing dictionaries. His alternative is direct case analysis, which likely would not be applicable in dynamically typed languages, since you don't know ahead of time what the types of the constituents of your expression will be. On the other hand, this isn't extensible at run-time either.

As for dynamic non-OO languages, I'm not aware of many examples outside Lisp/Scheme. Common Lisp's CLOS makes Lisp a proper OO language and provides dynamic dispatch as well as multiple dispatch (you can add or remove generics and methods at run-time, and they can key off the type of more than just the first parameter). I don't know how this is usually implemented, but I do know that it is usually an add-on facility rather than a built-in facility, which implies it's using functionality available to the would-be monkey-patcher, and also that certain versions have been criticized for their lack of speed (CLISP, I think, but they may have resolved this). Of course, you could implement this type of parallel dispatch mechanism within an OO language as well, and you can probably find plenty of examples of that.

If you were using purely-functional persistent maps or dictionaries, you could certainly implement this faculty without even needing the chain of inherited maps; as you "modify" the map, you get a new map back, but all the existing references to the old map would still be valid and see it as the old version. If you were implementing a language with this facility you could interpret it by putting the type->function map in the Reader monad and wrapping your interpreter in it.